# Whats the problem with int *p; *p=23;

Tags: c, pointers

Yesterday in my interview I was asked this question. (At that time I was highly pressurized by so many abrupt questions).

```
int *p;
*p=23;
printf("%d",*p);
```

Is there any problem with this code?

*I explained him that you are trying to assign value to a pointer to whom memory is not allocated.*

But the way he reacted, it was like I am wrong. Although I got the job but after that he said Mohit think about this question again.
I don't know what he was trying to say. Please let me know is there any problem in my answer?

**EDIT**
I added the code on the sheet;-

```
int *p;
p=malloc(sizeof(int));
*p=23;
printf("%d",*p);
```

This must be the perfect code...Am i right..

**EDIT2**

```
int *p;
*p=23;
 OR
int *p=23;
```

I think both has problem. Cause some body is saying about the title of the post.

Comment: Good question. And the interviewer is right to ask such questions. They clearly show what one's "five years of C development" are worth.

Comment: Please note your question title and your question text are semantically different.

Comment: Fixed the title to what was (I think) intended

Comment: We were saying that int *p; *p=23; is radically different from int *p=23;. Both have problems, but different ones. Also, the code that you say in edit one to be "perfect" still suffers from undefined behaviour, in the line *p=23;, so it is perfect for crashing, if anything.

Comment: what reason did the interviewer give for this not being correct?  (I would have accepted your answer as correct / understanding the failure of the code)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"trying to assign value to a pointer to whom memory is not allocated"

I think you just misphrased it a bit. You're not trying to assign a value to a pointer, you're trying to assign a value to *the referand* of a pointer.

Since the pointer is uninitialised, this is, as you say, undefined behaviour. The pointer doesn't refer to anything (at least not validly - as other answers point out, the bits of storage of `p` might just so happen to contain a value which is the address of some memory location, and your code might overwrite that. The standard permits anything to happen with UB, but knowing something about your implementation you can often take a shrewd guess).

So probably in the interviewer's mind you have the right idea, but it's valuable to have it exactly straight in your mind and in your speech what the difference is between a finger and the moon, and which one you're talking about.

Comment: yaa i explained him in a proper way that its a undefined behavior cause pointer doesnt have any memory and without allocating memory u r assign value to the un initialized memory. I just want to confirm the logic was correct na.. Or my ansswer os completely wrong.

Comment: No, you're not "assigning a value to uninitialized memory" either. If I give you an envelope to deliver, and the address (pointer value) is smudged (uninitialised), then you can't deliver it. You aren't trying to deliver it to a smudged *house*, though, you're trying to figure out what house a smudged *envelope* refers to. It doesn't refer to any house, so you can take the rest of the afternoon off (undefined behavior).

Comment: So for instance if I write `char c; char *p = &c; *p = 'X';`, then I'm assigning a value ('X') to uninitialised memory (the variable `c`). Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 14):

`p` is not initialized - it stores *some address*. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

The address stored in `p` may be mapped into the address space of the process or may be not mapped. If it is mapped some unrelated (but maybe important for the program) data is stored at that address. So either your program crashes immediately because of memory protection or you change *some* data belonging to the program. The consequences of the latter may vary - maybe nothing happens, maybe you don't notice, maybe you corrupt important data and the program breaks apart - classic undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

'p' is pointing to an unknown location, and not to a "not allocated" memory.

The difference is that since it's undefined, it could point to an allocated memory, even if this memory wasn't meant to be accessed by this function.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(char** argv) {
  // THIS POINTER IS NOT DECLARED (SO IT'S NOT USABLE/INVALID)
  int *p;
  // 1) SO RESERVE MEMORY AND SET POINTER TO VALID MEMORY...
  p=malloc(sizeof(int));
  // 2) ...CHECK IF ALLOCATION WAS OK...
  if (p) {
    *p=23;
    printf("%d",*p);
  } else printf("sorry, no memory");
  // 3) ...AND FINALLY DE-ALLOCATE MEMORY (FREEING IS IGNORED WHEN p IS NULL)!
  free(p);
}
```

Comment: And check the return value of `malloc` for null.

Comment: I think *p=23; should happen after allocation check was performed.

Comment: Don't call `free()` unless the `malloc()` succeeded, either. That call should immediately follow the `printf()`, inside the `if`.

Comment: @Steve: Calling free() with parameter NULL is ok and allowed. So this ensures memory de-allocation in every case. This is helpful for complex switches and eases overview (ok, this example is quite simple).

Answer (score 3):

> int *p=23;

This is completely different. Here you're declaring a pointer, and assigning it a value of 23. Meaning it now points to the memory location 23, which may or may not contain readable data.

But simply assigning an arbitrary value to a pointer without dereferencing it is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 2):

int *p;

initailly the above pointer contains some garbage value( invalid adress value or un allocated address ).

*p = 23;

then your are trying to put some value (23) in the invalid memory leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the example doesn't allocate memory for the value 23, it also won't compile in the first place because you've got two characters in your characted constant (which is meant to be a string). Eg, replace '%d' with "%d" in the printf-statement.